# Tensorflow Batch Normalization: tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've recently picked up Tensorflow and and have been trying my best to adjust to the environment. It has been nothing but wonderful! However, batch normalization using tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm has been a little tricky. 
Right now, here is the function I'm using:

```
def batch_norm(x, phase):
    return tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x,center = True, scale = True,
                    is_training = phase, updates_collections = None)
```

Using this, I followed most documentation (also Q & A) that I've found online and it led me to the following conclusions:

1) is_training should be set to True for training and false for testing. This makes sense! When training, I had convergence (error < 1%, Cifar 10 Dataset).

However during testing, my results are terrible (error > 90%) UNLESS I add (update collections = None) as an argument to the batch norm function above. Only with that as an argument will testing give me the error I expected.

I am also sure to use the following for training:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):                                       # Ensures, Updating ops will perform before training
    with tf.name_scope('Cross_Entropy'):
        cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(                                         # Implement Cross_Entropy to compute the softmax activation
            tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))  # Cross Entropy: True Output Labels (y_), Softmax output (y_conv)
        tf.summary.scalar('cross_entropy', cross_entropy)                       # Graphical output Cross Entropy

    with tf.name_scope('train'):
        train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-2).minimize(cross_entropy)       # Train Network, Tensorflow minimizes cross_entropy via ADAM Optimization 

    with tf.name_scope('Train_Results'):
        with tf.name_scope('Correct_Prediction'):
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))  # Check if prediction is wrong with tf.equal(CNN_result,True_result)
        with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))     # Find the percent accuracy, take mean of correct_prediction outputs
            tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)                                # Graphical output Classification Accuracy
```

This should make sure that the batch normalization parameters are updating during training.

So this leads me to believe that update collections = None is just a nice default to my batch normalization function that during testing function will be sure not to adjust any batch normalization parameters.... Am I correct?

Lastly: Is it normal to have good results (Expected Error) when, during the testing phase, having batch normalization turned on AND off? Using the batch norm function above, I was able to train well (is_training = True) and test well (is_training = False). However, during testing (is_training = True) I was still able to get great results. This is just gives me a bad feeling. Could someone explain why this is happening? Or if it should be happening at all?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Unstable `decay` rate (default 0.999) for moving averages might be the reason for reasonably good training performance but poor validation/test performance. Try a slightly lower `decay` rate (0.99 or 0.9).  Also, try `zero_debias_moving_mean=True` for improved stability.

You can also try different batch sizes and see if validation performance increases. Large batch size can break validation performance when batch normalization is used. See [this](http://forums.fast.ai/t/batch-normalization-with-a-large-batch-size-breaks-validation-accuracy/7940).

Comment: Thank you for the information! However, I'm using a small batch size (100) and have varied it to a few other ranges. I haven't used a batch that has been particularly large due to GPU memory restrictions.

Comment: I'll look into changing the decay rate and improving the stability like you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Is your phase variable, a tensorflow boolean or a Python boolean?

Comment: My phase is tensorflow boolean.